# Exporting FBX animations from Linked character rigs

Tags: animation, export, linked-data, .fbx, append

I'm fairly new to Blender and have been using and made an animation to practice myself to get used to Blender and using the Rain v2.1 Rig, and I made the animation by Linking the character rig from its original file, but when exporting it using the methods that I have learned so far nothing seemed to work when I exported it to Unity. Is there a specific way, or method on exporting FBX from animated linked character rigs?